# Oracle Trigger with update view and after insertion of rows

Tags: oracle

I want to fire a trigger whenever I insert/delete rows in 2 tables belonging to two different schema. I have a sql query as:

select n.name as name, count(distinct d.projects) as count
from emp n, dep d
where n.dep=d.dep
group by n.name;

When I insert or delete rows from these tables emp and dep, I want to fire a trigger automatically to update view containing the above sql query.
I am using Oracle Database. Please advise me how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "update view"?  A view is just a stored query, it doesn't store any data so you don't need to update anything.  The view will always reflect the current state of the data.

Comment: Is this a materialized view? if it's a normal view, you don't have to update it .. it'll figure it out by itself. If it's a materialized view, create it with "on commit" option .. and again, it'll update on its own.

Comment: The view contains above query. Is it normal view or materialized?

Comment: You'd need to tell us.  Did you do a `CREATE VIEW`?  Or a `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`?  If you created a materialized view, what refresh options did you specify?  If, somehow, you don't know, what type of object do you see in `all_objects`?